# import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using eclipse
The import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle cannot be resolved is the error i get.I tried update sdk and manually adding the jar but it doesnt resolve.
How to remove this error

Comment: prove that you have added everything correctly

Comment: @VladMatvienko Do you know the reasons due to which this error might be coming?

Comment: yes, the reason is that you added something wrong.

Comment: @VladMatvienko What do you mean specifically? 
Added Something wrong in the code?

Comment: no, you added the appcompat-v7.jar incorrectly

Comment: @VladMatvienko What is the correct way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

try compiling this in your app gradle dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
```

Comment: didnt i make it very clear that i was using eclipse?